# Facebook app using access tokens for multiple users behind the scenes

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am building a Facebook application whose purpose is to gather statistics about Facebook users by querying their profile pages every so often. There is a sign up process where a user consents to the application and is redirected to Facebook to authorize the app. After the app has received the user's permission, it stores the access token with the user's Facebook ID number.

Every so often I want to be able to run a script that loops through all the access tokens in my database and queries the corresponding user's profile page. I am using Facebook's PHP SDK for development and therefore receive long-lived access tokens.

However, I am running into the issue of the 60 day expiration of the access token. I don't know how I can renew these access tokens, since the user does not initiate API calls; my own script does and therefore it has no information about the user being logged in or not when trying to run an API call. Is there any way to renew these access tokens behind the scenes without any information about the user whom I'm trying to query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend access token validity since offline\_access deprecation](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation)

Comment: Well this is exactly the reason Facebook deprecated it's offline access permission. In order to keep a valid access token (even an extended one), your users will have to be actively using your application.

Comment: @Igy the difference is that I need to do this without user interaction.

Comment: @Lix that's a bummer for applications that are trying to do research

Comment: @jru - Facebook is not meant for research. It's a social network. This is why you are facing this problem.